# Typical files for .gitignore file for Xpages

Tags: git, xpages, gitignore

What are the typical files you include in your .gitignore file for your XPages project?

For now I have:

```
# NSF settings 
ODP/AppProperties/database.properties 
ODP/AppProperties/$DBIcon 
ODP/.classpath 
ODP/Code/Jars/commons-lang-2.6.jar.metadata ODP/Code/ScriptLibraries/j2ee.javalib 
ODP/Resources/Files/environment.properties ODP/Resources/Files/environment.properties.metadata 
ODP/Resources/IconNote 
ODP/Resources/AboutDocument 
ODP/Resources/UsingDocument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to build a new application (nsf) from scratch from your Git project I would not recommend to ignore these files.

Typically my .gitignore file is empty for XPages projects. I commit all files.

I can recommend [Swiper from OpenNTF](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Swiper) for easier handling of metadata for the files in the nsf.